# wpf, binding data to child of another usercontrol

Tags: wpf

i am trying to bind a **Textblock**'s **Text** property of **MainWindow** to a **Listbox**'s **Items.Count** of another **Usercontrol**, and the textblock of Mainwindow failed to read the value of binding source.

but if both textblock and listbox belong to the same usercontrol or window, the binding is fine.

i know i can define a property of in the usercontrol and make it exposed to other framework elements(e.g. textblock) of Mainwindow, and then it can be bond.

i just cannot understand why the binding to the listbox of another usercontrol failed. any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

here below is the sample i made for better explanation.

**UserControl Xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="stackoverFlow.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stackoverFlow"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbDemo">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="element 01"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="element 02"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="element 03"/>
            </ListBoxItem>

        </ListBox>
        <!--binding to the control of the same usercontrol is fine-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lbDemo,Path=Items.Count,StringFormat='there are {0} items in the listbox.'}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverFlow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stackoverFlow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 x:Name="userControlDemo"/>

        <Separator Margin="0 5 0 15"/>
        <!--binding failed-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=userControlDemo,Path=lbDemo.Items.Count, StringFormat='there are  {0} items in the listbox of Usercontrol1'}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: `lbDemo` is not a public member of `UserControl1`, and even if it were, it's not a property. Both need to be true for the binding syntax you want to work. If you want literally that to work, you need to add a public property to `UserControl1`, which returns the `lbDemo.Items.Count` value and bind to that. That said, there is something fundamentally wrong with the whole approach. Unfortunately, there's not enough context to redirect; suffice to say, you should use MVVM, and have no need for one UI element to bind to some property of another UI element like that.

Comment: great explanation. now i understood why binding cannot be done to a control contained in another UserControl, basically because it is not public. about MVVM framework, which one would you recommend, like MVVMLight, prism, mirco caliburn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User control, you should add a get accessor like this:

```
public int ListCount {
    get {
        return this.lbDemo.Items.Count;
    }
}
```

And in your Main Window, you call it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=userControlDemo, Path=ListCount, StringFormat='there are  {0} items in the listbox of Usercontrol1'}" />
```

Comment: If this works for you, I recommend mark this an answer